# Oracle Query for data in specific quarter from previous year

Tags: sql, excel, oracle

I have an excel spreadsheet that queries an oracle database for some data.  I sue excel to do some calculations and then post it share point.

I need to gather data from the 4th quarter of last year (2013)  my data selection look like this

```
Where "TABLE". "DATEFIELD" >= ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'MONTH'), - 1)
 and  "TABLE". "DATEFIELD" <  TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'MONTH')
```

How would I make this look at October, November, and December of 2013?

Comment: not clear what you are asking...

Answer (score 2):

```
where to_char("TABLE"."DATEFIELD", 'qyyyy') = '42013'
```

Please refer to [this oracle documentation link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF51079) for the specific meaning of `q` and `yyyy`.

In short, `to_char(<date expression>, <format model>)` returns a string whose meaning is specified by the *format model* and whose values is dependent on the *date expression*.
Here, the `q` tells to return a single character identifying the *quarter* of the *date expression* (4 = Oct through Dec). Then `yyyy` specifies to return the year as four characters.

All dates that fall within the last quarter of 2013 are, according to this format model, equal to `42013`.